# PHP displaying in browser

Tags: php

SO i create the most basic php code possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "hello";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I wrote this in notepad and saved it with a .php extension. However I am having an issue where when I open it up with chrome/firefox, it is displaying the code, and not the "hello" from the echo statement. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: You need a web server software (Apache/Nginx/IIS) to serve PHP file, web browser does not interpreter PHP code

Comment: https://dev.to/nearlythere/what-do-you-need-for-a-php-local-development-environment-1hk4

Answer (score 0):

You need a php service to handle php extension files.

You can try : AppServ from https://www.appserv.org/en/

After install, place the php file in the root folder (By default `C:/AppServ/www`). Access `http://localhost/{your_file_name}.php` to view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Web server on your computer
If you are using windows, will install XAMPP

And then copy a.php and paste into xampp/htdocs/
And run http://localhost/a.php on browser

Note: you will run the Apache on XAMPP control panel
[xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6fnh.png)